# Database implementation

Tags: database-schema

I have some trouble converting some specifications to sql tables :

The scenario is as follow :

an employee (there is already an EMPLOYEE table) can have one or several lists of employees, and an employee can belong to one or more of these lists.

Example :
employee_1 has 2 lists, list_1_1 and list_1_2.

list_1_1 holds employee_2, employee_3 and employee_4.

list_1_2 holds employee_3 and employee_5.

employee_1 can in turn belong to a list of another employee.

I first thought of a table with these columns :

list_name;owner_id;employee_id

but then, what would the primary key of that table be ? I am sure there is a better way to achieve this, but I'm stuck.

Comment: You can try OwnerID and ListId as PK also..

Answer (score 0):

There can be 1 table emp:
Emp Id | Emp Name...etc with EmpID as PK

Then Emp_List_Map table:
EmpID | ListId  with (EmpId and ListId) as PK

And then List Table:
ListId | EmpID   with (ListId and EmpID)  as PK

This is what I think..

Comment: I did consider this solution, but the problem is that the PK in the List table wouldn't be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You need an "employee list" membership table. This is very similar to the concept of users and roles, where each user can be assigned to zero or more roles.

See [How to design a user/role schema in a SQL Server database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879143/how-to-design-a-user-role-schema-in-a-sql-server-database) for a good example datamodel; just rename "user" to "employee" and "role" to "list".