# Junction table indexing in many-to-many relationship

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, many-to-many, junction-table

Let's say we have a `PRODUCT` table, `ORDER` table and a junction table `PRODUCT_ORDER`.

I create a junction table with the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE public."PRODUCT_ORDER" (

    product_id bigint NOT NULL,
    order_id bigint NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_ORDER_PK" PRIMARY KEY (product_id, order_id),

    CONSTRAINT "FK_TO_PRODUCT" FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
        REFERENCES public."PRODUCT" (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,

    CONSTRAINT "FK_TO_ORDER" FOREIGN KEY (order_id)
        REFERENCES public."ORDER" (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Also an index for the PK was created automatically:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PRODUCT_ORDER_PK" ON public."PRODUCT_ORDER" USING btree (product_id, order_id)
```

It is expected that there will be practically only read operations for these tables and I would like to index the junction table intelligently.

Usually, I additionally create an index for foreign keys manually, e.g. for `one-to-many` relationship, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX "index_name" ON schema_name."table_name" (fk_column_name);
```

My question is: Do I need to create two indexes for foreign keys in addition to PK-index like this:

```
 CREATE INDEX "FK_TO_PRODUCT" ON public."PRODUCT_ORDER" (product_id);
 CREATE INDEX "FK_TO_ORDER" ON public."PRODUCT_ORDER"(order_id);
```

Or is it unnecessary, meaningless and the index for the PK will be enough?

**In general, I'm interested in how to intelligently/correctly index the junction tables for many-to-many relationship?**

If you need any clarification, let me know and thanks in advance!

Comment: Useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/571309/how-to-properly-index-a-linking-table-for-many-to-many-connection-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need to create two additional keys.  Your primary key index will work for the first key (`product_id`) as well as the pair.

You need one additional index on `order_id`.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer, +1 ! Could you please explain, why primary key index will work for the first key as well as the pair, but not for the other `order_id` key?

Comment: @GeorgeLvov . . . That is how (b-tree) indexes work.  An index conceptually stores the data sorted by the keys, so if the index is sorted by `key1` then `key2`, it is sorted by `key1`.  I happen to think the MySQL documentation on this subject does a decent job of explaining this (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).  This functionality is similar across databases.

Comment: Think of a phone book, it is a two column index on (last lane, first name). It can be used to efficiently search for people by last name, but not by first name. Order matters!

Comment: Got it, thank you all!